# Some fonts way too large in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

Any idea how I can restore the default look for File Explorer in Windows 10?  The font used on the desktop is also way too large.

[image: current look of File Explorer]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your desktop and go to Display Settings.  Check to see if 'Scale and layout' is set to 100%.

You can also try going to Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Fonts > Font Settings and hitting 'Restore default font settings'.